# Firebase getChildrenCount() returns always '1'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I try to fetch all users that are available. For that every user has a parameter that is either "true" or "false". I want to return the amount of the users where that parameter is "true".

In that case the data looks like this:
[image: data structure]

I tried to do it like this, the code is cut to the necessary part:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase, mUsers;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    private String userID;

    private Button startButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Query allAvailable = mUsers.orderByChild("available").equalTo("true");

                allAvailable.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                            long xy = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(xy), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                        }

                    }

                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

However I try to do it, the `getChildrenCount()` always returns the value 1. Why doesn't it return the amount of all users that have the parameter available is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ValueEventListener` :

```
mUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
Query allAvailable = mUsers.orderByChild("available").equalTo("true");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     long xy = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
}
  @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()):

> `public long getChildrenCount ()`
>
> Returns
>   The number of immediate children in the this snapshot

When you use `addChildEventListener`, you are looping inside the dataSnapshot and thus only getting 1 as a result from `getChildrenCount()`.

In the above code, the datasnapshot will return a snapshot of `user` node where `available` is equal to `true`, then when you add the listener you will be able to retrieve the number of all direct children under the node `users` that satisfy the above query.

Comment: Thank you, it works half way already. It does return the correct amount of available users for me, so thank you for that! But now my code is always executed when another user changes its state and I need it only when the button is clicked. Is there a way to deactivate the listener again afterwards?
I know about the `ListenerForSingleValueEvent` don't know if that would be a suggestion but then it starts returning the value 1 again. Do you know how do avoid that?

Comment: Yes use listenerforsinglevalueevent

Comment: I did a mistake on using `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`, it works perfectly. Thank you for helping!

Comment: No problem!! Goodluck!!

Answer (score 0):

use a count variable to count how many are available and then show that
Something like this

```
            Int count = 0;
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Users us = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                String status = user.getAvailability();

                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    //anything you wanna do here
                }

            }                    @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```